# DeserializeObject from JSON to a Dynamic Type

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

In VB.NET, is it possible to deserialize a JSON string to a dynamic / unknown datatype, then read the values from the object?

```
    Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim o As Object = js.DeserializeObject(json)

    Dim s As String = String.Empty

    For Each i As PropertyInfo In o.GetType().GetProperties()
        s = String.Concat(s, i.Name) & "<br>"
    Next

    Response.Write(s)
```

It lists a bunch of things inside the object, but I can't seem to get to the value of these fields / properties.

Comment: can you show the JSON or provide a link

Comment: http://api.wunderground.com/api/0a3be834bc56c310/conditions/q/pws:KLABELLE7.json

Comment: `obj("current_observation")("display_location")("state")` works fine - you might want to have it parsed out into classes just so you can see what the relationships are and/or use NewtonSoft and `JObject.Parse` instead

Comment: what do you mean parsed out into classed?

Comment: it is hard (for me, anyway) to instantly see what the relationships are in the json string.  there are several online tools which will look at the string and create class structures from it.  Even if you dont use them to deserialize, they help understand what is nested where etc